# pandas retain styling when reformatting cells - without reparsing string to numbers

Tags: python, pandas, styling

For a pandas data frame of:

[image]

I want to reformat it to:

[image]

However, the styling is lost. How can I retain the styling whilst reformatting?
Instead, formatting after the fact would also be fine. But parsing the string to numbers to validate styling conditions seems complicated as the number of digits is not constant.

It was constructed by:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_source = pd.DataFrame({'foo': [['0.001', '0.001', '0.190'], ['0.220', '0.029', '0.000'], ['-0.754', '0.202', '0.000'], ['-0.393', '0.191', '0.042']], 
                  'bar': [['-9.076', '2.548', '0.001'], ['7.111', '2.461', '0.005'], ['-35.263', '13.918', '0.013'], ['-0.393', '0.191', '0.042']], 'feature': ['first', 'second', '3rd', '4th']})
df_source.index = df_source.feature
df_source = df_source.drop(['feature'], axis=1)

def highlight_significant(x, sign_level_1, sign_level_2):
    if x is np.nan:
        return ''
    else:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            p_value = float(x[2])
            if float(x[0]) > 0:
                if p_value < sign_level_2:
                    return 'font-weight: bold;background-color: lightgreen'
                elif p_value < sign_level_1:
                    color = 'lightgreen'
                    return 'background-color: %s' % color
                else:
                    return ''
            else:
                if p_value < sign_level_2:
                    return 'font-weight: bold;background-color: yellow'
                elif p_value < sign_level_1:
                    color = 'yellow'
                    return 'background-color: %s' % color
                else:
                    return ''
        else:
            return ''
df_source = df_source.style.applymap(highlight_significant, sign_level_1=0.05, sign_level_2=0.01)
display(df_source)


# various variants are calculated, now combine selected metrics
df_summary = pd.DataFrame({'feature':[], 'foo': [], 'bar':[]})
# print(df_summary.iloc[0])

def format_results(r):
    if len(r)> 1:
        coefficient = r[0]
        std_err = r[1]
        return f'{round(float(coefficient), 2)} ({round(float(std_err), 2)})'
    else:
        # handle empty
        return '-'

d = df_source.data
def construct_record(name, column, index, df):
    df.loc[index] = [name] +  \
    [format_results(d.foo[column])] + \
    [format_results(d.bar[column])]
    return df

df_summary = construct_record('Descriptive name 1', 'first', 0, df_summary)
df_summary = construct_record('Descriptive name 2', 'second', 1, df_summary)
df_summary.index = df_summary.feature
df_summary = df_summary.drop(['feature'], axis=1)
df_summary
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution, idea is return `DataFrame of styles` and then use [`Styler.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) for another modified `DataFrame`:

```
#removed styles
styles = df_source.applymap(lambda x: highlight_significant(x, sign_level_1=0.05, sign_level_2=0.01))
print (styles)
                                                foo  \
feature                                               
first                                                 
second    font-weight: bold;background-color: green   
3rd      font-weight: bold;background-color: yellow   
4th                        background-color: yellow   

                                                bar  
feature                                              
first    font-weight: bold;background-color: yellow  
second    font-weight: bold;background-color: green  
3rd                        background-color: yellow  
4th                        background-color: yellow 

df = df_source.applymap(lambda x: f'{x[0]}({round(float(x[1]), 2)})')
print (df)
                  foo             bar
feature                              
first      0.001(0.0)    -9.076(2.55)
second    0.220(0.03)     7.111(2.46)
3rd       -0.754(0.2)  -35.263(13.92)
4th      -0.393(0.19)    -0.393(0.19)

#styler need function, so used lambda
df.style.apply(lambda x: styles, axis=None).to_excel('file.xlsx')
```

Another idea, similar:

```
styles = lambda x: df_source.applymap(lambda x: highlight_significant(x, sign_level_1=0.05, sign_level_2=0.01))
print (styles)
<function <lambda> at 0x000000000DEF21F8>

df = df_source.applymap(lambda x: f'{x[0]}({round(float(x[1]), 2)})')
print (df)

df.style.apply(styles, axis=None).to_excel('file.xlsx')
                  foo             bar
feature                              
first      0.001(0.0)    -9.076(2.55)
second    0.220(0.03)     7.111(2.46)
3rd       -0.754(0.2)  -35.263(13.92)
4th      -0.393(0.19)    -0.393(0.19)
```

Comment: Is it also possible to retain the style after constructing a fresh row in `format_results`? The reason is: I have multiple `df_source` from various runs of a regression. Now after selecting the desired data points and reformatting them (before creating the result string) is it possible to define a style on the row?

Comment: @GeorgHeiler - I think not, is necessary same index, columns in both.

Comment: So for that case, I would need to use a regex to parse the result string to the two numbers and then apply the styling as desired? Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: @GeorgHeiler - I think not easy. Becase `style`s has many restrictions. But if return some way DataFrame filled by styles (with same size like new DataFrame), then solution working. Problem should be how create this Dataframe, I think

Comment: In fact it is even more obvious: the 3-rd column (p-value) is missing in the reformatted output ...

Comment: So selection first (but keeping all 3 values), and then your approach to reformat and keep the style

Comment: But when trying to reproduce your code 1:1 (I have pandas 1.0.1) : `df.style.apply(styles, axis=None)` fails with: Styler' object has no attribute 'style. And I do not receive the nicely formatted result you demonstrate in `print(df)`.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler tested in pandas 0.25.1 :(