# pandas apply style and change contents of cell

Tags: python, pandas, styling

For a dataframe of:
[image]

I can apply a styling of:
[image]

But instead, I want to drop the last value from the triplet and encode it using styling. I.e.:
[image]

However, I do not know how to combine both steps.
For pandas 25.x [pandas retain styling when reformatting cells - without reparsing string to numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60588197/pandas-retain-styling-when-reformatting-cells-without-reparsing-string-to-numb) demonstrates a possible answer, however, I need to get this to work for pandas 1.0.1.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': {'first': ['-0.89495', '0.48868', '0.06978'],
  'second': ['0.50249', '0.07999', '0.00000'],
  '3rd': ['-0.75436', '0.20239', '0.00031']},
 'bar': {'first': ['-0.49294',
   '0.61195',
   '0.42228'],
  'second': ['0.35000', '0.10999', '0.00191'],
  '3rd': ['-0.62354', '0.28775', '0.03250']}})

def highlight_significant(x, sign_level_1, sign_level_2):
    if x is np.nan:
        return ''
    else:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            p_value = float(x[2])
            if float(x[0]) > 0:
                if p_value < sign_level_2:
                    return 'font-weight: bold;background-color: lightgreen'
                elif p_value < sign_level_1:
                    color = 'lightgreen'
                    return 'background-color: %s' % color
                else:
                    return ''
            else:
                if p_value < sign_level_2:
                    return 'font-weight: bold;background-color: yellow'
                elif p_value < sign_level_1:
                    color = 'yellow'
                    return 'background-color: %s' % color
                else:
                    return ''
        else:
            return ''

display(df)

display(df.style.applymap(highlight_significant, sign_level_1=0.05, sign_level_2=0.01))

def format_regression_results(r):
    if len(r)> 1:
        coefficient = r[0]
        std_err = r[1]
        p_value = round(float(r[2]), rounding_digits)
        result = f'{round(float(coefficient), rounding_digits)} ({round(float(std_err), rounding_digits)})'        
        return result
    else:
        return '-'

df.foo = df.foo.apply(format_regression_results)
df.bar = df.bar.apply(format_regression_results)
df
```

## edit

Indeed:

```
def make_float(x):
    return [float(x[0]), float(x[1]), float(x[2])]

df.foo = df.foo.apply(make_float)
df.bar = df.bar.apply(make_float)
```

it is possible to convert the strings to floats.
[image]

The reformat:

```
styles = lambda x: df.applymap(lambda x: highlight_significant(x, sign_level_1=0.05, sign_level_2=0.01))
dx = df.applymap(lambda x: f'{x[0]}({round(float(x[1]), 2)})')
display(dx)
```

works. However, the styling is still lost.

Comment: Your first dataframe contains lists of floats, while your second contains list of strings, so does your sample. Probably the first thing you want to do is to convert all to floats.

Comment: sure - but still the styling is not applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usiing different colors and float values the appraoch outlined from [pandas retain styling when reformatting cells - without reparsing string to numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60588197/pandas-retain-styling-when-reformatting-cells-without-reparsing-string-to-numb) works just fine.

```
def make_float(x):
    return [float(x[0]), float(x[1]), float(x[2])]

df.foo = df.foo.apply(make_float)
df.bar = df.bar.apply(make_float)

display(df)

def highlight_significant(x, sign_level_1, sign_level_2):
    if x is np.nan:
        return ''
    else:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            p_value = float(x[2])
            if float(x[0]) > 0:
                if p_value < sign_level_2:
                    return 'font-weight: bold;background-color: cyan'
                elif p_value < sign_level_1:
                    color = 'cyan'
                    return 'background-color: %s' % color
                else:
                    return ''
            else:
                if p_value < sign_level_2:
                    return 'font-weight: bold;background-color: yellow'
                elif p_value < sign_level_1:
                    color = 'yellow'
                    return 'background-color: %s' % color
                else:
                    return ''
        else:
            return ''

styles = lambda x: df.applymap(lambda x: highlight_significant(x, sign_level_1=0.05, sign_level_2=0.01))
dy = df.applymap(lambda x: f'{x[0]}({round(float(x[1]), 2)})')
display(dy)
dy.style.apply(styles, axis=None)
```